# Why is my page automatically scrolling to the bottom/

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a website and somehow whenever I load the site or click on a link, it jumps to the bottom.

When I removed the footer from my application.html.erb file,the site is not scrolling to the bottom.
But I want to keep the footer.
Does anyone know what the problem is or how I could prevent it?

```
application.html.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>NightJobs</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
</head>
<body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
 <div id="content"></div>
 <div id="container">
<%= yield %>
</div>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</body>
</html>

Layouts _footer.html.erb

<nav class="footer">
    <div class="footer-link-container">
    <ul>
       <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path,class: "link-new" %></li>
       <li><%= link_to "Help",  help_path,class: "link-new" %></li>
       <li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path,class: "link-new" %></li>
       <li><%= link_to "About",  about_path,class: "link-new" %></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="subscribe-container">
  <section class="subscribe">
    <div class="subscribe-pitch subscribe-pitch-new">
       <%= image_tag("envelope.png", alt: "envelope icon", :class => "envelope")%>
      <p>Sign up for<br> daily updates<p>
    </div>
    <form action="index.html" method="post" class="subscribe-form">
      <input type="email" name="email" class="subscribe-input" id="subscribe-spacing" placeholder="Email" autofocus>
      <form action="index.html" method="post" class="subscribe-form">
      <input type="email" name="email" class="subscribe-input" id="subscribe-spacing" placeholder="Zip Code" autofocus>
      <button type="submit" class="tfbutton tfubutton-subscribe">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
  </section>
</div>
```

CSS for _footer.html.erb classes and id's

```
/* footer */

.footer {
  text-align: center;
  height: 170px;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-top: -3em;
   background-color: #090909;
}

.footer-link-container{
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.footer li{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 35px;
}

.link-new{
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    color: $grayLight;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(51,51,51);
    word-spacing: 0px;
}

.link-new:hover{
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Newsletter */

.subscribe-container {
  height: 120px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 100px;
  padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  border: solid 2px white;
  background-color: #b5d77c;
}


.subscribe-form{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: 120px;
}

.subscribe-input{
  width: 140px;
  height: 15px !important;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  top-padding: 100px; 
  line-height: 5px;
  font-size: 5px;
}

#subscribe-spacing{
margin-bottom: 13px !important;

}
.subscribe-pitch{
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  bottom-padding: 50px;
  width: 90px;
  float: left;
  color: #090909;
}


.envelope{
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}


.tfubutton-subscribe {
  margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  margin-right: 60px !important;
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 30px !important;
    padding: 5px 25px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: solid 1px #0076a3; border-right:0px;
    background: #0095cd;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#00adee), to(#0078a5));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #00adee,  #0078a5);
    border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
  }

  .tfbutton:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #007ead;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0095cc), to(#00678e));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #0095cc,  #00678e);
  }

  /* Fixes submit button height problem in Firefox */
  .tfbutton::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
  }
```

Let me know if you need more information

Update:

It seemed that the subscribe section in the footer was the problem.
I removed the subscribe box for now, which resolves the problem.
It had to do with the HTML I think, because when I removed the CSS the page still jumped to the bottom.

Comment: Right-click and view-source. Post the result

Comment: I just posted the view-source. Hope you can find something

Comment: Your `<nav class="footer">` tag has not ended.. rectify it

Comment: Not to mention any kind of focussing on the footer can happen in one of the scripts

Comment: I added a </nav> at the end of the code of _footer.html.erb but it still jumps to the bottom of the page.

Comment: @mplungjan what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Perhaps you have some script that does a $(".footer").focus() - when you remove the footer, do you get an error in the console?

Comment: @mplungjan I'm sorry I'm very new. Where would I find the script in which this function might be in? Also, what do I need to write in my console to see if I get an error? Or do i just check the console in which my server is running?

Comment: Please refer to my update above

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `autofocus` from the fields in the footer or move the subscription form higher on the page.

PS: they are both called email and both have autofocus - I am sure the zip should be type=text

```
 <form action="index.html" method="post" class="subscribe-form">
  <input type="email" name="email" class="subscribe-input" 
   id="subscribe-spacing" placeholder="Email" XXXautofocusXXX>
  <form action="index.html" method="post" class="subscribe-form">
  <input type="email" name="email" class="subscribe-input" 
  id="subscribe-spacing" placeholder="Zip Code" XXXautofocusXXX>
  <button type="submit" class="tfbutton tfubutton-subscribe">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I made the changes and this resolved my problem. Thank you so much